# Can't run Ansible Playbook on M1 Mac

Tags: ansible

When I run `ansible-playbook` command I get the following error:

```sh
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'bool'>

The error appears to be in '/Users/mycomputer/.ansible/roles/wtanaka.jq/tasks/compat_sudo.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: install python-apt on ansible < 1.6.0 and ubuntu et al
  ^ here
```

I took a look at that [playbook](https://github.com/wtanaka/ansible-role-jq/blob/master/tasks/compat_sudo.yml), and I'm not seeing anything that sticks out at me:

```sh
---
- name: install python-apt on ansible < 1.6.0 and ubuntu et al
  sudo: yes
```

Ansible Version:

```
ansible 2.10.7
  config file = /Users/mycomputer/Tools/xeno-ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/mycomputer/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/3.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Mar 26 2021, 15:28:17) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]
```

Would this be an issue with Ansible and my M1 Mac or is there something in the playbook that is wrong?

Comment: Random guess: try removing the `<` character in the name field. Perhaps ansible sees it and thinks you're trying to compare two values.

Comment: What was `sudo` a really long time ago is now `become` I guess the usage of `sudo` as been deprecated in 2.10.

Comment: @legoscia I tried removing the `<` but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε On my old computer I used this same playbook but I was using Ansible 2.8. I was able to install Ansible 2.9 but I ran into the same issue.  I was unable to install 2.8 because of an error (I think because of M1 chip).

Comment: So, I was wrong, it has been removed in 2.9, not 2.10: *All previously deprecated sudo/su and module locale global settings have been removed.* https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.9.rst

Comment: And so, yes, the role you are trying to use is not compatible with your version, not much we can do about it. Try contacting the maintainer or filling an issue on their Github

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks.  Do you know if I should be able to run 2.8 with the M1 Mac?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε This is the error I get: `python@3.7: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was that I was using an old playbook that isn't compatible with Ansible 2.9+. I had to install ansible using Rosetta2, similar to [this](https://diewland.medium.com/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-macbook-m1-87c5b0fcb3b5).